# Sorting div using data attribute

Tags: angularjs, aem

I have 3 divs within a container and in my CMS tool have the flexibility to author or update where the 3 div is going to be positioned within the container.
When the page is loaded I need the 3 divs to be sorted in ascending order based on data-attribute value authored.

For example, i can update the position in the following order and it needs to sorted in ascending order when the page is loaded.

```
<div class="container">
     <div data-pos="2">Content</div>
     <div data-pos="3">Content</div>
     <div data-pos="1">Content</div>
</div>
```

I need it be sorted as below based on data attribute,

```
<div class="container">
     <div data-pos="1">Content</div>
     <div data-pos="2">Content</div>
     <div data-pos="3">Content</div>
</div>
```

I need to achieve this in angularJS. 
I have seen many examples of this being done in javascript/jQuery but none in angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame this issue by creating a custom directive as below and the sorting works fine,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
    myApp.directive('customsort', function () {       
        return {
         restrict: 'A',
      link: cutomSorting
            }
      function cutomSorting(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
       
       if(attrs.customsort == "second")
       {    
        var firstElement = document.querySelector("[customsort='first']");
        element.parent()[0].insertBefore(firstElement, element[0]);        
       }
       if(attrs.customsort == "third")
       {
        var SecondElement = document.querySelector("[customsort='second']");
        element.parent()[0].insertBefore(SecondElement, element[0]);        
       }
      }
        
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body  ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div class="container" >
     <div customsort="third">Content ABC</div>
     <div customsort="second">Content DEF</div>
        <div customsort="first">Content XYZ</div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```